# Column values of multilevel indexed DataFrame are not properly updated

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(6,5), index=[list('aaabbb'), list('XYZXYZ')])

print(df)

df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['a'], 3] /= 10

print(df)
```

From the above code I expected below table:

```
      0   1   2   3   4
a X   0   1   2   0.3   4
  Y   5   6   7   0.8   9
  Z  10  11  12  0.13  14
b X  15  16  17  18  19
  Y  20  21  22  23  24
  Z  25  26  27  28  29
```

But the actual result is as below table:

```
      0   1   2     3   4
a X   0   1   2   NaN   4
  Y   5   6   7   NaN   9
  Z  10  11  12   NaN  14
b X  15  16  17  18.0  19
  Y  20  21  22  23.0  24
  Z  25  26  27  28.0  29
```

What went wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need specify second level by `:` for select all values:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['a', :], 3] /= 10
print(df)
      0   1   2     3   4
a X   0   1   2   0.3   4
  Y   5   6   7   0.8   9
  Z  10  11  12   1.3  14
b X  15  16  17  18.0  19
  Y  20  21  22  23.0  24
  Z  25  26  27  28.0  29
```

Solution with slice:

```
df.loc[(slice('a'), slice(None)), 3] /= 10
print(df)
      0   1   2     3   4
a X   0   1   2   0.3   4
  Y   5   6   7   0.8   9
  Z  10  11  12   1.3  14
b X  15  16  17  18.0  19
  Y  20  21  22  23.0  24
  Z  25  26  27  28.0  29
```